# Use Ruby and nokogiri to extract poorly constructed content within an element

Tags: ruby, split, nokogiri

I'm looking to write content to a csv row from a poorly constructed source site.  My csv row is simply:

```
COMPANY_NAME,WEBSITE,EMAIL,TEL1,TEL2,FAX,STREET,CITY,STATE,ZIP,COUNTRY
```

Unfortunately the source doesn't have clean ID's and classes to search on.  In between a bunch of "useless to me" elements is everything I need bundled up inside of a single `<p>` element like this:

```
<h2 class="lead">Contact Details</h2>
<br>
<p><!--what I want is in here -->
  <strong>COMPANY_NAME/strong> <br>
  STREET<br>
  CITY, STATE ZIP<br>
  COUNTRY<br>
  Tel: +1 555 555 5555<br>
  Tel: +1 555 555 5555<br>
  Fax: +1 555 555 5555<br>
  Email: <a href="mailto:EMAIL_ADDRESS</a><br>  
  URL: <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.COMPANY_WEB_ADDRESS.com">
  www.COMPANY_WEB_ADDRESS.com</a><br>                 
</p>
```

So, my current code (that I'm sure you will have a great laugh over) is this:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.SOURCE/'))
page.css('h2.lead')[0].next_element.next_element
```

This ugly line finds the 1st occurrence of the pages h2 element with class lead. I had to explicitly use [0] to apply methods?  Did I capture the element wrong?  Then I grab the `<p>` element two elements after my selection using two "next_element" calls.  I cringed writing this but I couldn't seem to traverse nth levels after my selection! Finally the `<p>` element and all of it's content I desire is captured! YAY Mini victory!

The output is very ugly (not to mention my one liner is extremely ugly) and I'm unsure of the best way to "break up" the `<p>` content into an array I can output to a csv.

I'm half temped to write this into a file as is and use linux terminal to clean it all up... that would be cheating and quiting!

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get at the p with:

```
p = page.at('h2.lead + br + p')
```

To break up the content, maybe it's good enough to do:

```
p.children.map &:text
```

Comment: Thank you, Much cleaner!  Although some of the array elements look like this:', "\r\n\r\n\r\n _LOTS OF WHITE SPACE HERE_                    Tel: +1 555 555 5555",'  I did pm=p.children.map &:text then pm[10] to get that.  Wonder if I can easily remove \r\n's and white space?  Thanks again, huge help!

Comment: You're welcome. To strip whitespace try: `p.children.map{|c| c.text.strip}.reject(&:empty?)`

Comment: WOW, your good!  Your two lines have a ton of power I need to learn how to harness and apply in other places!  Thank you!

Comment: Try `p.xpath('//text()').text`

Comment: Well the `strong` is a child of `p` so yes it gets it (if you fix the markup)